# Is the wave function of a coherent state just a Gaussian density?

Tags: coherent-states

The formula giving the wavefunction of a coherent state looks pretty complicated, but am I correct in saying it is just a Gaussian distribution function? i.e.

$$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$$

for some $\sigma$ and $\mu$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state

Comment: *The formula giving the wavefunction of a coherent state looks pretty complicated.* Which formula do you mean? Please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 2):

> The formula giving the wavefunction of a coherent state looks pretty complicated, but am I correct in saying it is just a Gaussian distribution function

Per [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state), the wavefunction for the coherent state of a simple harmonic oscillator is an exponential of the form:
$$
\psi(x,t) \sim e^{-a(x-b)^2 + ixc + id}\;,
$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real functions of time only.

The probability density is a Gaussian of the form:
$$
|\psi|^2 \sim e^{-g(x-h)^2}\;,
$$
where $g$ and $h$ are real functions of time only.

---

If by "coherent state" you are referring to some other system (other than a simple harmonic oscillator) the coherent state might look like the product of gaussians, or might look different altogether. But, I think you are using the term to mean a coherent state of a single simple harmonic oscillator.

Comment: But the wavefunction is a “Gaussian” with *complex* $\sigma$ and $\mu$, isn’t it?

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, some coefficients are complex. I updated my answer to say that.